# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - list images from database

Tags: php, jquery, database, file-upload, blueimp

I need help for this. Please advise me.

I use Blueimp jQuery File Upload script and I add database connection and I add all upload images write in db file.
If you know this script when you open upload page again script show old uploaded files

but **i need only show my property_id images** expample **property_id='1'** how can I do that?

My infrastructure is like this

db table name: property_images

image_id    property_id   order   image

1             1          1     image.jpg

2             1          2     image2.jpg

3             1          3     image3.jpg

4             2          1     image.jpg

//------------ this code part write all images in database------------------------------

```
function query($query) {
$database = $this->options['database'];
$host = $this->options['host'];
$username = $this->options['username'];
$password = $this->options['password'];
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
if (!$link) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);
if (!$db_selected) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($link);
return $result;
}
function add_img($whichimg)
{
    $property_id= $_POST['property_id'];
$add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO property_images (image,property_id) VALUES ('".$whichimg."','".$property_id."')") or die(mysql_error());
return $add_to_db;
}
function delete_img($delimg)
{
$delete_from_db = $this->query("DELETE FROM property_images WHERE image = '$delimg'") or die(mysql_error());
return $delete_from_db;
}
```

I think this script use this codes for image listing but how can be change this code

```
protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
    if ($this->is_valid_file_object($file_name)) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $file_name;
        $file->size = $this->get_file_size(
            $this->get_upload_path($file_name)
        );
        $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
        foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
            if (!empty($version)) {
                if (is_file($this->get_upload_path($file_name, $version))) {
                    $file->{$version.'_url'} = $this->get_download_url(
                        $file->name,
                        $version
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        $this->set_file_delete_properties($file);
        return $file;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: the code you have given is not related to selecting the image, it doesn't contain "select" query in it. find a code which has "select" query with property_images is a table name

Comment: Look uploadhandler page is here please check

[link](http://www.eratech.net/UploadHandler.txt)

Answer (score 2):

The listing is done through the `get_file_objects` method (which uses the `scandir` method). Replace the scandir with your select query. It then iterates over the result calling the `get_file_object` method you mentioned.
So the `get_file_objects` is the method you'll want to alter.